# need help on configuring fortigate firewall CLI code for bulk ipmacbinding by importing a ip/mac entries list file

Tags: python, perl, command-line-interface, firewall

i am facing a problem in ip/mac binding in fortigate 200d, the thing is i have a list of 3000 entries of IP/MAC addresses, i have kept them in a csv file.

This is what i am looking for

1.I want to write a code which can import that file

2.I want execute this code snippet inside a loop until all entries are updated.

```
config firewall ipmacbinding table
edit <index_int>
    set ip <address_ipv4>
    set mac <address_hex>
    set name <name_str>
    set status {enable}
end
```

3. with the help of above code snippet each time i have to manually enter the the IP,MAC and Name values for 3000-times, instead i just want to import a file and from that file values should be added.
4. In few places i came to know that it can achieved with the help of perl/python script but i am not aware of that.

i googled but i didn't find anywhere about this information, so i hope that i would get help to get this task done.

Thanks.

Format of CSV File is

```
Index   IP       Mac                name
1   10.10.17.1  aa:bb:cc:00:11:22   first
2   10.10.17.2  cc:dd:ee:ff:22:33   second
3   10.10.17.3  33:44:11:3f:00:88   third
```

[Formal of CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj4VP.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the format of your CSV also.

Comment: i have added the format of CSV file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the fortigate CLI so i will assume you know how it works and what to do with it. below is a small attempt that if it doesnt work exactly will hopefully put you on the correct trail. I have assumed that when you run the config command, the terminal normally waits for user input. so in this case the perl script will pipe in that input.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $csv_file = shift;
open (my $cfh, '<', $csv_file) or die "Unable to open $csv_file: $!";
my @headers = split (' ', <$cfh>);

while(<$cfh>){
  my %config;
  my @data = split(' ');
  @config{@headers}=@data;

  open(my $firewall, '|-', 'config firewall ipmacbinding table') or die "Unable to open 'config firewall ipmacbinding table': $!";
  print $firewall "edit ",$config{'Index'},"\n";
  print $firewall "set ip ",$config{'IP'},"\n";
  print $firewall "set mac ",$config{'Mac'},"\n";
  print $firewall "set name ",$config{'name'},"\n";
  print $firewall "set status {enable}\n";
  print $firewall "end\n";
  close $firewall;
}
```

the above is written as an attempt to help you get started on how to make this work. as i said i have no experience with fotigate so you may need to tweek this a bit.

If i chose to print this just to my terminal screen as output like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $csv_file = shift;
open (my $cfh, '<', $csv_file) or die "Unable to open $csv_file: $!";
my @headers = split (' ', <$cfh>);

while(<$cfh>){
        my %config;
        my @data = split(' ');
        @config{@headers}=@data;

        #open(my $firewall, '|-', 'config firewall ipmacbinding table') or die "Unable to open 'config firewall ipmacbinding table': $!";
        print  "config firewall ipmacbinding table\n";
        print  "\tedit ",$config{'Index'},"\n";
        print  "\tset ip ",$config{'IP'},"\n";
        print  "\tset mac ",$config{'Mac'},"\n";
        print  "\tset name ",$config{'name'},"\n";
        print  "\tset status {enable}\n";
        print  "end\n";
        #close $firewall;
}
```

it produces the following

```
config firewall ipmacbinding table
        edit 1
        set ip 10.10.17.1
        set mac aa:bb:cc:00:11:22
        set name first
        set status {enable}
end
config firewall ipmacbinding table
        edit 2
        set ip 10.10.17.2
        set mac cc:dd:ee:ff:22:33
        set name second
        set status {enable}
end
config firewall ipmacbinding table
        edit 3
        set ip 10.10.17.3
        set mac 33:44:11:3f:00:88
        set name third
        set status {enable}
end
```

hopefully this is enough for you to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot. can you just tell how i can run that code, i am not aware it.

Comment: I mean on windows how to execute that code to get that output and write it on to a separate output file.

Comment: put the perl code in a file. and then call it with the csv file with all the data in it. `C:\Users\CD00119621>perl ip_mac_setup.pl ip_mac_setup.csv`